# WSO2 Throttling API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have gone through read the various questions involving throttling on stack overflow. However, I didn't find anyone with a similar issue to what I'm seeing. I have gone through the tutorials and setup process on the WSO2 site regarding throttling.

This is what I have done:

1. Setup an additional tier to allow 5 calls per minute on the
   following levels (Advanced Throttling, Application Throttling,
   Subscription Throttling).
2. Edit the API and set the subscription tier level to the new custom
   tier
3. Set the Application to the new tier level
4. Set the Advanced Throttling Policy to apply to the API, then I saved & published
5. Ran 1100 HTTP requests from an application that calls the API on an
   interval every second. Every request made was successfully processed
   without any throttling.
6. I installed version 1.9 of API manager and setup the very same rules
   The requests were throttled correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm not really sure if it is a bug or a configuration issue on my end.

Regards

Comment: Is this a single node or a distributed setup?

Comment: For my testing setup, it is a single node. [Edit] I also unsubscribed and again subscribed to the API after the changes to the subscription tier level were made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much digging in the WSO2 documentation. I have found that in order to use the advanced throttling techniques (which are enabled by default) you must use Traffic Manager (which is disabled by default).

There are instructions on how to use Traffic Manager in the WSO2 documentation. If advanced throttling is disabled the basic throttling works as expected.

It took some time to discover this as the documentation doesn't clearly make the distinction very clear in the documentation.

I hope this helps someone having a similar issue.